# How to freeze first column in Interactive grid in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have an interactive grid with source as : select header_1,header_2,header_3 from data;

I want HEADER_1 ,i.e. first column to freeze and others to scroll on display.

Also i am aware this can be done by end user by freezing the column, but can this also be done from back end?

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you freeze column on IG, just got to Action/Report/Save and save it for all users.

To ensure that end user can't unfreeze column, go to IG column which you Froze, go to attributes in JavaScript initialization code and paste this code:

```
 function(config) {
  config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
   noHeaderActivate: true
 };
 return config; }
```

That's it.